# Jquery on click function is not working for img in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I've got a bunch of radio buttons and images. I'm trying to make the images clickable because I would like to use the images in place of the radio buttons. I'm using CSS to hide the radio buttons and in Firefox this script works great, but it doesn't work at all in IE (nothing happens when you click on the image). Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').click(function() {
        $(this).next().click();
    });
});​
```

I'm using jquery 1.6.1.

I do not want to change the image after it is clicked, I only want to be able to click the image and use it in place of the radio box. I am able to click the image in Firefox, but not in IE.

I've tried changing the script to this and it works in IE without any problems:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('img').click(function(){
alert("Show me");
});
});
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML or better yet, a jsFiddle?

Comment: Version of jQuery you're using?

Comment: Can you also provide your HTML code to make your question more clear?

Comment: Did you intend to replace the image with a different one after it's clicked?

Comment: `$(this).next().click();`..this code isnt working ? or ur `img` click isnt working ?

Comment: Press F12 to check console error on IE8. If there's something wrong, it will show you.

Comment: There are no errors in IE, it's just that nothing happens when I click on the image.

Comment: what happens if you stick 'alert("boop");' in the click function?

Comment: When I change the code to trigger an alert it works fine in IE. I tried this script with no problems in IE:  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').click(function(){

alert("Show me");

});
});

Comment: Perhaps this is not the code that is broken. I suspect that it's the code that executes when the radio button is clicked that is breaking. If you unhide the radio button, is it being selected when you click the image?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the visibility:hidden or display:none (I've tried both), when I click the image, the radio button does get selected in IE and Firefox. Is there any way to still do this in IE without showing the radio button?

Comment: without any html markup on what doesn't work this will be very hard to say what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I changed the z-index of the input[type=radio] so that the radio button is now underneath the image, it seems to be working in IE. Do you know if there are any drawbacks to doing it this way?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/uJ9tK/1/

The code you have shown us is correct. Whether you hide the radio buttons or not, they are being clicked. Whatever you do when the radio buttons are clicked is the part that is broken. I tested this in IE7, 8, 9 and compatibility mode.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! Now that I have it working by hiding the radio buttons behind the image, is there a way to change the image once it's been clicked? Or maybe just change the border around the image to let the user know that image is the one that has been selected (clicked on)?

Comment: Sure. `$(this).css('border', '10px');` That will change the border styles.

Comment: Would I just add it to the last part of the script like this?  $(document).ready(function () {
$('img').click(function(){
  $(this).next().click();
$(this).css('border', '10px');
});
});

Comment: Anywhere inside of the img click, yes. You can change any style that way with `.css(`

Comment: Thank you for the help on that! It does work in jsfiddle but not on the site. I think it has something to do with the 'onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack' script that is in the link code, which is causing the page to reload (I can't remove this as it's part of the built in system the site is on). Do you know if there a way to get around that and to make the border change after the image has been clicked, even though the page is reloading?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15395/discussion-between-user1172854-and-isaac-fife)